# How to set Windows server active driectory group policy Slideshow (live wallpapers)?

Tags: group-policy

I had installed windows 2019 server and windows 11 in clients. I had configured active directory . I hade created Organisational unit. Then applied Group policy in organisation units.

i have configured custom wallpaper policy.
“User Configuration” -> “Policies” -> “Administrative Templates” -> “Desktop” -> “Desktop” -> “Desktop Wallpaper”

on first instance it displayed walleper on clients when i made it center then on second day
another boot  its not showing  the  walleper i tried to change many time different setting. how control  it.

Secondly  there is setting  in windows 11 client local  pc wallpaper backgroud  setting to change to slide show mode where it changes walllpaper on every mindute

is there any option in windows server  active driectory  users group policy to deploy slide shows of animated wallpapers . i have seen an policy of live wallpaper but there is no option to slect tje wallpepers by ourself.

Thank youy in advane  waiting for a solution

Thank y